# CSS styles are not working in my jsp file im my java ee jsp-servlet application

Tags: java, css, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am building a web application in using JSP/Servlet and I'm having issues applying my CSS styles in my JSP files. All my JSP are in WEB-INF/ directory and my CSS file is the styles directory at the same level as the WEB-INF. I am using Eclipse Oxygen.

Here is the directory structure of my web app.
[image: project tp1 directory structure]

Here the content of my web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.skillupsoft.tp.servlets.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CreationClient</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.skillupsoft.tp.servlets.CreationClient</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CreationClient</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/creationClient</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CreationCommande</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.skillupsoft.tp.servlets.CreationCommande</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CreationCommande</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/creationCommande</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is CreationCommande servlet.

```
public class CreationCommande extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/creerCommande.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

And here is my jsp file : creerCommande.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Création d'une commande</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/styles/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="creationCommande" method="get">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Informations client</legend>
                <label for="nomClient">Nom<span class="requis">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="nomClient" name="nomClient" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="20"><br>

                <label for="prenomClient">Prénom</label>
                <input type="text" id="prenomClient" name="prenomClient" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="20"><br>

                <label for="adresseClient">Adresse de livraison<span class="requis">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="adresseClient" name="adresseClient" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="20"><br>

                <label for="telephoneClient">Numéro de téléphone<span class="requis">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="telephoneClient" name="telephoneClient" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="20"><br>

                <label for="emailClient">Adresse email</label>
                <input type="email" id="emailClient" name="emailClient" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="60"><br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Informations commande</legend>

                <label for="dateCommande">Date <span class="requis">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="dateCommande" name="dateCommande" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="20" disabled="disabled"><br>

                <label for="montantCommande">Montant<span class="requis">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="montantCommande" name="montantCommande" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="20"><br>

                <label for="modePaiementCommande">Mode de paiement<span class="requis">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="modePaiementCommande" name="modePaiementCommande" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="20"><br>

                <label for="statutPaiementCommande">Statut de paiement</label>
                <input type="text" id="statutPaiementCommande" name="statutPaiementCommande" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="20"><br>

                <label for="modeLivraisonCommande">Mode de livraison</label>
                <input type="text" id="modeLivraisonCommande" name="modeLivraisonCommande" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="20"><br>

                <label for="statutLivraisonCommande">Statut de la livraison</label>
                <input type="text" id="statutLivraisonCommande" name="statutLivraisonCommande" 
                        value="" size="20" maxlength="20"><br>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Valider">
            <input type="reset" value="Remettre à zéro">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that I've referenced my css file il the jsp code like this:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/styles/style.css"/>`

I am a little bit confuse because this code worked last week and today it does'nt work anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First make a `resources` folder inside `webcontent`. Then move `css` folder inside `resources` folder. Now In your `servlet-context.xml` file write

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

And in your jsp page write

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="
      <c:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/> "/>
```

If you haven't add jstl add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

in your `pom.xml`

And add this tag `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`
on the top of jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

The location of static web assets are mal-configured in your project.
Move the styles folder into WEB-INF folder. It will work fine.